# Registering with Google Schemas: What is the process when sending from multiple email addresses?

Tags: google-schemas

I work for a direct marketing company that sends many emails on behalf of many clients, and we wish to start using Actions in Gmail. I am in charge of heading up the testing of this.

I am concerned about this step in the registration process:

> Send a real-life email coming from your production servers (or a
>   server with similar DKIM/SPF/From:/Return-Path: headers) including the
>   markup / schema to schema.whitelisting+sample@gmail.com.

Since we will be sending email on behalf of many clients, we will need to send from a multitude of sender addresses. Is it possible to whitelist our company as a whole or will we need to whitelist each email that we wish to send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to list all the email id's to be whitelisted or create a common domain and then you can request for whitelisting.

However, in order to whitelist these emails id's the emails you are requesting should be transactional not promotional emails. Like the email notifications that user has been subscribed for or emails related to order processing etc.

You can refer to Actions / Schema Guidelines in this [page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google) for more details.

Hope that helps!

Comment: "you have to list all the email id's to be whitelisted" Where can I list them? The [registration form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1PA-vjjk3yJF7MLPOVKbIz3MBfhyma2obS8NIZ0JYx8I/viewform?pli=1) appears to only have a place for one email to be entered.

Comment: You can add them in the description of the email.

Comment: Ok, awesome. So if an email id is whitelisted, can I send multiple go-to actions from that email or will each action need to be independently approved?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple Go-to actions?

Comment: Once you get whitelisted for an email ID, as long as the email ID and the type of action are same as you requested and approved for, it is ok.

Comment: Ok, so one action might be "Complete Your Registration" which would be in an email that would be automatically sent after a span of time where the user creates an account, but hasn't completed the required registration form. and so the link for that action will need to be unique to that user, so that it would automatically log them in and take them to the form.

Then another action could be "Claim my Guide" which would also be a unique link that would log the user in, but would take them to a different page where they would enter their information to be sent the Public Service Guide.

Comment: No, both the use cases are are different. You have to request separately. Its something like the text on the action button is also taken into consideration.